# CRUD multiple model in one view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

i want use multiple model in one view and add records in multiple table from view
my db like below image:
(i work with vs2012 mvc4 and EF)
[image]

i create four model for each table and class "PreOrder" for repository of all

```
 public class Orders
{
    public long OrdersId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public long OrderListId { get; set; }
    public int? CountProduct { get; set; }
    public string CountPrice { get; set; }
    public string VisitorsName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
}

 public class Product
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
  public class Customers
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "-")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "-")]
    ...
}
public class OrderList
{
    public long OrderListID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> OrdersId { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Count { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DisCount { get; set; }
}
public class PreOrder
{
    public Customers _Customer { set; get; }
    public Product _Product { set; get; }
    public Orders _Order { set; get; }
    public OrderList _OrderList { set; get; }
  }
```

i want use name,family,customerid from tblcustomers
and productId,NameProduct,Price from tblProducts
and all fields of tblOrders and tblOrderList
how can i create one view to fill tables Orders and OrderList??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved problem like below article:

[How to Use ViewModel with ASP.NET MVC ?](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html)

[How to Use ValueInjecter with Asp.net MVC ViewModel ?](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-use-valueinjecter-with-aspnet.html)

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your links in your answer. Should that site go down or the content be removed, your answer becomes useless to future viewers.